# Tabs at the bottom of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

I'm having a `Fragment` from a mother activity and I want inside it to display two tabs using `FragmentTabHost`. But I would like the tabs to be located at the bottom of the fragment not at the top, as it is the default.

**MainFragment.java:**

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private View rootView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        //tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);;

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), ConnectFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), ManageFragment.class, null);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        return tabHost;

    }
}
```

The layout which I am using is pretty basic and when I run this version everything works but the tabs are displayed at the top of the fragment.

**fragment_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

When I am running a slightly different version which is supposed to put the tabs at the bottom of the fragment-according to other threads of this site- i get an error.

**fragment_main_v2.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Thrown error:**

> android.view.InflateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I can imagine that something is going wrong with the

> android.view.InflateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.